# QTextCodec::availableCodecs returns codec duplicates

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

So, i need to make result of this function to be unique.

My task is simple: i'm just want to show encoding select dialog for text-processing application.
My first naive solution looks like this:

```
QList<QByteArray> encodings = QTextCodec::availableCodecs ();
QSet<QTextCodec*> unique_codecs;
unique_codecs.insert (QTextCodec::codecForName ("autodetect"));
unique_codecs.insert (QTextCodec::codecForName ("system"));
foreach (QByteArray e, encodings)
{
    if (QTextCodec* c = QTextCodec::codecForName (e))
    {
        if (!unique_codecs.contains (c))
        {
            m_encodings.append (e);    // QStringList to store encodings
            unique_codecs.insert (c);
        }
    }
}
```

Do you have any other ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is `availableMibs()` methods that returns list of MIBs - which are unique IDs for codec and won't have duplicates. `QTextCodec::codecForMib(int)` will then let you retrieve the codec in question.

```
foreach (int mib, QTextCodec::availableMibs()) {
    m_encodings << QTextCodec::codecForMib(mib)->name();
}
```

On my machine I get 111 available mibs and 804 available codec names

Comment: Thanks, your code is working well.
But can you explain briefly the meaning of `MIB` term? Google doesn't give the right answer to me :/

Comment: See http://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets/character-sets.xhtml (referenced from Qt documentation)

Comment: I just want to know the meaning of `MIB` term :) In your article it used in the encoded way.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the question (how to make the list with unique items with the help of availableMibs()) was given, so here is the addition to that - why there were duplicates.

QTextCodec::availableCodecs() returns a list of codecs with all popular aliases, so, for example, the codec cp-1252 will be present as two aliases (or more, if any): cp-1252 and windows-1252. It can be useful if the user needs to choose the encoding via combo-like list with automatic item filtration. He can type cp-1252 or windows-1252 and have the same result even if he doesn't remember the alternative alias.

Comment: Hm, i'm usually remember only codes for such encodings. I.e. `1252`. So i don't find those aliases useful. Also do you know ready-to-use custom GUI control to show the unique encodings list?
Now i've made the custom list model and use it with QListView.

Comment: The list of codec names - unique or not - is just a usual list, so QListView, QListWidget, QComboBox, etc. will suit for this.

Comment: Ok, i understand you. But QList*View* is redundant in your list - this control can't show QList directly, it needs QStringListModel for this.